# Is there any open-source code for a hybrid 2D mesh (triangles and quadrilaterals)?

Tags: mesh-generation, unstructured-mesh

The question is pretty much the title. Note that I have lots of experience using open-source meshing tool, e.g. Gmsh and OpenFoam blockMesh & snappyHexMesh. Nevertheless, I have no idea on how to generate the 2D mesh shown below when doing some simple test in SU2 (CFD code).

I believe some commercial meshing kits can do this job, but no experience using any commercial codes as I mainly work with open-source mesh/CFD codes.

Any idea which mesh libraries (e.g. CGAL, OpenMesh) can make hybrid 2D tri/quad mesh?

---

**Update 1:** The quad-mesh around the rectangle seems like beautiful O-Grid style. Any idea achieve this?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use Gmsh for this purpose. I show an example below.

```
// Points
Point(1) = {-2, -2, 0, 1.0};
Point(2) = {2, -2, 0, 1.0};
Point(3) = {2, 2, 0, 1.0};
Point(4) = {-2, 2, 0, 1.0};
Point(5) = {-10, -10, 0, 2.0};
Point(6) = {10, -10, 0, 2.0};
Point(7) = {10, 10, 0, 2.0};
Point(8) = {-10, 10, 0, 2.0};

// Lines
Line(1) = {1, 2};
Line(2) = {2, 3};
Line(3) = {3, 4};
Line(4) = {4, 1};
Line(5) = {5, 6};
Line(6) = {6, 7};
Line(7) = {7, 8};
Line(8) = {8, 5};

// Surfaces
Line Loop(1) = {3, 4, 1, 2};
Plane Surface(1) = {1};
Line Loop(2) = {7, 8, 5, 6};
Plane Surface(2) = {-1, -2};

// Meshing
Transfinite Line {3, 4, 1, 2} = 10 Using Progression 1;
Transfinite Surface {1};
Recombine Surface {1};
```

Obtaining the following mesh.
[image]

### Update

```
// Points
Point(1) = {0, 0, 0, 1.0};
Point(2) = {-1, -1, 0, 1.0};
Point(3) = {1, -1, 0, 1.0};
Point(4) = {1, 1, 0, 1.0};
Point(5) = {-1, 1, 0, 1.0};
Point(6) = {-5*Sqrt(2)/2, -5*Sqrt(2)/2, 0, 1.0};
Point(7) = {5*Sqrt(2)/2, -5*Sqrt(2)/2, 0, 1.0};
Point(8) = {5*Sqrt(2)/2, 5*Sqrt(2)/2, 0, 1.0};
Point(9) = {-5*Sqrt(2)/2, 5*Sqrt(2)/2, 0, 1.0};
Point(10) = {-10, -10, 0, 2.0};
Point(11) = {10, -10, 0, 2.0};
Point(12) = {10, 10, 0, 2.0};
Point(13) = {-10, 10, 0, 2.0};

// Lines
Line(1) = {2, 3};
Line(2) = {3, 4};
Line(3) = {4, 5};
Line(4) = {5, 2};
Line(5) = {6, 2};
Line(6) = {7, 3};
Line(7) = {8, 4};
Line(8) = {9, 5};
Line(9) = {10, 11};
Line(10) = {11, 12};
Line(11) = {12, 13};
Line(12) = {13, 10};
Circle(13) = {8, 1, 9};
Circle(14) = {9, 1, 6};
Circle(15) = {6, 1, 7};
Circle(16) = {7, 1, 8};

// Surfaces
Line Loop(1) = {11, 12, 9, 10};
Line Loop(2) = {13, 14, 15, 16};
Plane Surface(1) = {1, 2};
Line Loop(3) = {7, 3, -8, -13};
Plane Surface(2) = {-3};
Line Loop(4) = {14, 5, -4, -8};
Plane Surface(3) = {4};
Line Loop(5) = {1, -6, -15, 5};
Plane Surface(4) = {-5};
Line Loop(6) = {6, 2, -7, -16};
Plane Surface(5) = {-6};

// Meshing
Transfinite Line {8, 7, 6, 5} = 10 Using Progression 1;
Transfinite Line {14, 13, 16, 15, 1, 4, 3, 2} = 10 Using Progression 1;
Transfinite Surface {3};
Transfinite Surface {2};
Transfinite Surface {5};
Transfinite Surface {4};
Recombine Surface {2, 3, 4, 5};
```

[image]

Comment: Well done. However, the rectangle should be a hole, and mesh around the boundary should be quad-mesh.

Comment: @KOF, your question was about getting a hybrid mesh, not getting your particular mesh.

Comment: I knew transfinite in Gmsh can make quad-mesh, but can you make the 2D mesh shown above using this approach?

Comment: @KOF, see my update.

Comment: Pretty close. thanks. I would prefer O-grid style more around the obstacle.

Comment: This is like a multi-block grid but grid is not smooth at block boundaries. Maybe @KOF wants smooth grids.

Answer (score 1):

The picture you've linked in your post is without doubt generated by Pointwise. The O-grid style seems to be generated via hyperbolic extrusion.

I am not aware of any open source software that can achieve that. But the best alternative I've found so far is using Salome.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).